# How to save array of objects into DTO class

Tags: json, ajax, aem, sling, sling-models

So I have passed data in ajax as:

```
{
   “name” : “Rahul”,
   “age” : “23”,
   “information” : [
      {
         “id” : “901”,
         “role” : “developer”
      }
   ],
   “salary” : “21000”,
}
```

For this I have created two DTO classes as

```
class EmployeeDTO {
   @SerializedName(“name”)
   private String name;

   @SerializedName(“age”)
   private String age;

   @SerializedName(“information”)
   private List<InformationDTO> informationDto;

   @SerializedName(“Salary”)
   private String salary;

//Their getters and setters
}
```

I mentioned List because I took information as an array of objects. Then I have another DTO class

```
class InformationDTO {

   @SerializedName(“id”)
   private String id;

   @SerializedName(“role”)
   private String role;
}
```

Now in my Sling Servlet I am trying to get values of information array like

```
String information = request.getParameter(“information”);
```

But I am getting null value. How can I store this array `information` in my DTO class Employee using InformationDTO?
How to save array of objects into DTO class using sling servlet?

Comment: and you do not want to use existing rest apis because..?

Comment: Actually I am told to perform this using DTOs.. I am new to AEM so I don’t have much knowledge of this.